# Is there any alternative to the "-mtime" time in Linux?

Tags: find, openwrt, busybox

I would like to delete all files in a specific directory according to the creation (or modification) date. I know that to accomplish this task there is the command:

```
find /tmp/log -maxdepth 1 -name 'file*' -mmin +60 -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

The problem is that I'm using an OpenWrt system versione that doesn't support the flag -mtime (either -mmin). So is there any alternative to delete files according to the date?

Answer (score 0):

OpenWrt seems to replace most of the Linux commands with BusyBox versions (ouch) (see https://openwrt.org/docs/techref/busybox)
According to BusyBox documentation, the current version does support **-mtime**, but seemingly your version does not?  (I'd try it again, to make sure you didn't goof up the command line)
Anyway, how to get this done using BusyBox commands?

- Install a new version of BusyBox?
- or Install the "real" version of the **find** command
- or if this command `date -d '@946710000'` prints a date ~ 1/1/2000, try the following (**not** tested on BusyBox !!):

  ```
   cur=`date "+%s"`  # current timestamp
   old=`echo $cur|awk '{print $1 - (3600*10)}'`  # 10 days ago
   for f in *;do 
     date -r "$f" "+%s^$f"  # timestamp of named file
   done |
   awk -F'^' -v "old=$old" '$1<old{print $2}'  # older?
  ```

(assumes no ^ in filenames)